# Sum of any two consecutive squared integers mod 4 = 1

Tags: proof-verification

So today we were trying to prove algebraically that two consecutive integers `n, n+1` where each is squared mod 4 is 1. We got quite far, but I can't for the life of me find the notes which we made.
Not much more I can write really, if I find my notes I'll updated the question.
To rephrase the question: prove that `(n^2 + (n+1)^2) mod 4 = 1`

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be proving that $n^2 + (n+1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$? The question says consecutive squared integers but the text doesn't mention it...

Comment: Your title says "sum of any two consecutive squared integers" but in your post you mention only the sum of consecutive integers. Please check your question.

Comment: @Charter oh deary me you're right, updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ One of $\,n,n\!+\!1\,$ is even, the other is odd, and $ $ even$^2\equiv 0,\  $ odd$^2\!\equiv\{1,3\}^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$

Alternatively $\, n^2\!+(n\!+\!1)^2 = 2n(n\!+\!1)+1\,$ and, again, use one of $\,n,\,n\!+\!1\,$ is even.

Comment: could you explain this first option? what does the {1,3}^2 mean?

Comment: @Jacob Odd integers have form $\,4n+1\,$ or $\,4n+3,\,$ i.e. mod $4$ they are $\equiv 1$ or $3$, both of whose squares are $\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\{1,3\}^2 \equiv \{1^2,3^2\}\equiv \{1\}.\,$ It's clearer if you use $\,3\equiv -1\,$ then we can write it as odd$^2 \equiv (\pm1)^2\equiv 1\pmod4\ \  $

Comment: ah yes I see what you mean, thank you :)